# How to declare a function pointer in MASM?

Tags: winapi, assembly, masm, masm32

I have some masm syntax code on Windows in this way:

```
stru_40DBA0 dd 0FFFFFFFEh       ; GSCookieOffset ; SEH scope table for function 402B22
dd 0            ; GSCookieXOROffset
dd 0FFFFFFC0h       ; EHCookieOffset
dd 0            ; EHCookieXOROffset
dd 0FFFFFFFEh       ; ScopeRecord.EnclosingLevel
dd 0            ; ScopeRecord.FilterFunc
offset $LN19        ; ScopeRecord.HandlerFunc
.....
Foo proc near
....
$LN19:
....
```

masm will generate errors at the **offset $LN19** line, and I tried to modify it in this way:

```
PTR PROTO $LN29
```

Could anyone give me some help on how to declare this? Thank you!

Comment: I think `offset Foo` will work.

Comment: You need to define some place to store that offset, so it'd be something like `dd offset $LN19` (or `dq offset $LN19`).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes, I have also tried dd offset $LN19, but it will generate errors like "undefined symbol $LN19"

Comment: @500-InternalServerError But I have to store the offset of $LN19... $LN19 is inside the function foo

Comment: @computereasy: Oh -- your current problem is just that you're getting things out of order. You can define your structure after the label it needs an offset to. You also need to ensure the `$LN19` is visible at that point (which it may not be by default if it's inside of `Foo`).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thank you! I am sure in my code, the $LN19 is before the structure, but I don't know how to ensure the $LN19 label is visible to .rdata section's reference...?

Comment: @computereasy: Either declare it public: `public $LN19` or put a double colon after it: `$LN19::`. I generally prefer the latter for a situation like this.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It works! Could you please "answer" this question? Then I can mark your answer as correct:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two things you need to do:

1. Ensure the label is public so it can be seen where you're using its offset.
2. Ensure the label has been declared where you're using its offset.

The easy way to do the latter is define your structure after the label itself has been defined.

To make the label public, you can either declare it public explicitly, like:

```
public $LN19
```

...or where you've defined the label, you can use two colons instead of one:

```
$LN19::
```